# Trying to find the longest string in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

how do I find the longest name in an array in ruby.  here is what I tried:

```
people = ["john", "clark", "stan", "mike", "nick", "devon"]


def find_longest_name(people)
  longest_name = nil
  longest_name_length = -1
  people.each do |friend|
    if friend.length > longest_name_length
      longest_name = frined
      longest_name_length = friend.length
    end
  end
 return longest_name
end
puts "#{longest_name_length}"
```

I am getting an error that says I have an undefined variable.

Comment: `frined` != `friend`

Comment: *Which* error do you get? Please, read the *entire* error, it will *tell* you a) *exactly* where to find the undefined variable and b) what the *precise* name of the variable is. Look at the name. Are you 1000000% sure that that is the name of the variable?

Comment: In `puts "#{longest_name_length}"`, `longest_name_length` is defined inside method definition. Will not be accessible from outside.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
people.max_by(&:length)
```

You mispelled `friend` into `frined` at this line

```
longest_name = frined
```

Answer (score 0):

For maximum

```
people.map(&:length).max
```

For minimum

```
people.map(&:length).min
```

If you want length for max string

```
h = {}
people.map{|a| h[a]= a.length}
h.key(h.values.max)
```